# create multiple pseudo elements in the same container

Tags: html, css, frontend

In this way, the last statement will be the only one visible due to the css cascade.
Isn't there an alternative way to have all three pseudo-elements in the same container?

```
div class="container"</div>

.container {
position: relative;
}

.container:after {
position: absolute;
content: "some text";
top: 10%;
left: 20%;
}

.container:after {
position: absolute;
content: "";
border: 5px solid yellow;
width: 50%;
top: 10%;
left: 20%;
}

.container:after {
position: absolute;
content: "";
border: 5px solid blue;
width: 60%;
top: 30%;
left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to have m0re than one after pseudo element on a specific element.  Could you describe the effect you want to achieve (eg. with a sketch of the outcome).

Comment: I thought so, thank you, for now I am creating small empty containers.
I was trying to have exactly this layout.

Comment: What gives the container any height or width?

Comment: That's one of the problems because I have to specify height and width anyway and it adds space I don't need.
What I would like to achieve is this 
https://blupper434342.imgur.com/all
I do not know how to position the two underlines and the five images

Comment: https://imgur.com/NLE6nde

Comment: I don’t understand what the first picture has to do with the question as there is no code relating to images in your question. And what should I be looking at in the second picture, just the h1 element and its yellow and blue underlines?

Comment: The code I wrote refers to my question in general,it is a generic example,because I wanted to know if there was an alternative method to add more pseudo elements in the same container.
You had asked me for a sketch and I sent you the photo of the layout I am trying to achieve without creating empty containers and adding all the elements (underlines + pics) to the same container.
Two underlines positioned below the h1 and 5 photos positioned like that.

Comment: Can we stick to trying to solve the underlines on the h1 element? What sets the width of those underlines?

Answer (score 0):

As it is not possible to have multiple before or after pseudo elements on one element, this snippet takes a different approach to placing the yellow and blue underlines.

They are drawn using CSS background-image with two linear-gradients on one pseudo element. Each is sized and positioned appropriately.

The snippet produces this:

[image]

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  --h: 0.5em;
  /* set this to the height of each underline */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 300%;
  height: 2em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ffff66, #ffff66), linear-gradient(cornflowerblue, cornflowerblue);
  background-size: 95% var(--h);
  background-position: left 0.75em, right 1em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Some text</div>
```

Obviously you will want to set the various dimensions to suit your particular case.

Comment: thank you it's very nice but it's the same thing I did.
I have to create the layout in the picture, with the 5 images arranged like that and the double underline under the header.
Using flexbox or grid doesn't seem like a solution to me, so I was thinking of positioning each element individually.
So if it's not possible to have more than one pseudo element for a single container, how would I go about creating the same layout?

Comment: 'It's the same thing I did' - I don't underestand what this means as you are not using background images in the code you give. You also have not included the code you have tried to position the images. Please update your question with the code you have tried, including the underlines being drawn the same way that I have shown and all the image elements.

Comment: you seem very professional and good.
You know for this kind of work( front end developer) there is no real school.
Unfortunately I'm really at the beginning, I've done many online courses, I've studied and I'm doing a lot of practice but it's not enough, because sometimes alone is hard.
I have to make a page for my company will you help me?
We could work on the same code and I could learn a lot by watching how you work.
You could do it in your spare time and when you have time of course.
We could use live share on VS and I can send you the material and the project by email.